# Jquery-UI sortable list not playing nice with reactive updates in Meteor template

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to implement a sortable list of objects with JQuery-UI in the manner described at http://differential.com/blog/sortable-lists-in-meteor-using-jquery-ui.

However, rather than sort a list of separate documents, I'm sorting a list of objects embedded within a single document. That is, I have a document like so:

```js
{  name: "Name of this Rolodex",
   cards: [{name: "...", rank: 0, id: "some-unique-id"},
           {name: "...", rank: 1, id: "some-other-unique-id"}, ... ]
}
```

And I just want to make the cards sortable. My template is as follows -- it's passed a single Rolodex as the context:

```xml
<template name="rolodex">
  Rolodex Name: {{name}}
  <div class="cards-list">
    {{#each sortedCards}}
      {{> cardTemplate}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And the helper JS file:

```js
Template.rolodex.helpers({
  sortedCards: function() {
    return this.cards.sort(function(cardA, cardB) {
      return cardA.rank - cardB.rank;
    });
  }
});

Template.rolodex.rendered = function() {
  this.$(".cards-list").sortable({
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      // Get dragged HTML element and one immediately before / after
      var el = ui.item.get(0)
      var before = ui.item.prev().get(0)
      var after = ui.item.next().get(0)

      // Calculate new rank based on ranks of items before / after
      var newRank;
      if(!before) {
        // First position => set rank to be less than card immediately after
        newRank = Blaze.getData(after).rank - 1;
      } else if(!after) {
        // Last position => set rank to be more than card immediately after
        newRank = Blaze.getData(before).rank + 1;
      } else {
        // Average before and after
        newRank = (Blaze.getData(after).rank + 
                   Blaze.getData(before).rank) / 2;
      }

      // Meteor method that updates an attribute for a single card in a
      // Rolodex based on IDs for the Rolodex and Card
      Meteor.call('cards/update',
                  Blaze.getData(ui.item.parent().get(0))._id, // Rolodex ID
                  Blaze.getData(el).id, // Card ID
                  {rank: newRank});
    }
  });
};
```

The problem I'm running into is that after sorting a card into its expected position, the DOM is then updated with the card in a new, wrong position. The server has the correct rankings stored though, and refreshing the page causes the card to be listed in its correct position (at least until another sort is attempted).

My best guess as to what is happening is that Meteor's templating system doesn't seem to understand that the JQuery-UI has moved the DOM elements around and is reactively updating my template in the wrong order.

For example, suppose my cards are: A, B, C. I move C such that we now have C, A, B. JQuery-UI updates the DOM accordingly and fires an event which results in C's rank being changed to be less than A's.

However, Meteor doesn't know that the DOM has already been altered by JQuery-UI. It does, however, see the change in rank to C and reactively updates the order of the list based on prior assumptions about what the list order was. In this case, we end up with B, C, A.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Meteor/Blaze uses an `_id` attribute to identify data objects and link them to DOM elements. This applies not only to arrays of documents returned by a Collection cursor, but to any array of objects. So in the above issue, the problem was that I used an `id` value to identify each card rather than `_id`. Switching `id` to `_id` fixes the issue and allows Blaze to properly update the DOM, even if the DOM has previously been modified by JQuery-UI's sortable plugin.

Comment: Using an _id is really the best way to manage sortable array of objects! Thanks

Comment: Ok so changing to _id worked which I'm grateful but is there any way I can get it working without this? I don't want to have to change my entire schema in my app

Comment: Mate, you save my life! And you saved a really great project! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Meteor reactivity force you to choose who is in charge of DOM updates.

While it is ok to let Blaze render the DOM and then manipulate it with a third party library (usually a jQuery plugin invoked in a `.rendered()` method), you are now in a condition in which Blaze doesn't know what happened to your DOM, so every subsequent reactive update could not be consistent.

This is the reason why, for **interactive and reactive** interface elements, we need a new class of plugins/components/packages Meteor-aware (or better reactive-aware). See for example the [difficulties](https://github.com/LumaPictures/meteor-jquery-datatables/issues/50) of porting [datatables.net](https://github.com/LumaPictures/meteor-jquery-datatables) to Meteor versus the Meteoric [reactive-tables](https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/reactive-table).

All that said, my hack to overcome this problem is to write some reactive code that takes care of detroying and rebuilding the plugin whenever the DB gets updated. This way, you restore the original DOM which Blaze is aware of, let him update it and then reinvoke your jQuery plugin. This is a far (very far) from optimal solution, but saved my day a couple of times.

For `.sortable()` maybe the best solution is to disable reactivity with option `{reactive: false}` in the `Collection.find()` so that when you update the attribute of a card with `Meteor.call` no redraw takes place but your interface is already consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't really want to disable reactivity (i.e. I do want the resort to happen if the server says it should), so that might just leave destroy and rebuild. That said, I'm a little perplexed as to why it seems to work with sets of documents from collections, but not an embedded array within a single document. In theory, both situations should trigger the same mismatch between the DOM and Blaze's model.

Comment: Ok, my explanation apply when the jQuery component completely mangle the DOM to accomplish his goal. This is not the case with `.sortable()`, so it could be something with the logic of your code. For example where does it come from `Blaze.getData(el).id `? According to your model it's `undefined`. Maybe if you publish a complete test-case app I can check it thoroughly.

Comment: Ah, your comment helped me figured it out. My model did have an `id` attribute (updated question to reflect that), but it should have been `_id`. Apparently, the `_id` attribute has special meaning to Blaze (which explains why sortable works with entire documents but not necessarily with arbitrary arrays of objects). Thanks again for your help.