# How to write a jQueryUI selectmenu with dynamic options into a Meteor Blaze template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am having trouble making the jQueryUI selectmenu work in a Meteor app when the options are dynamic. I am using:

- Meteor 1.4.1
- jQuery 2.2.4
- jQueryUI 1.11.4
- lodash 4.15.0

[physiocoder said on a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26948260/3465840), "The Meteor reactivity force you to choose who is in charge of DOM updates.".

I realize that this is fundamental to my problem here. Accordingly, there is no problem if a page/template can let Meteor load all the page content/data and then hand over DOM control to jQueryUI's widgets. However I have a case where I want to have my cake and eat it too -- I want to have Meteor reactively feed the options for a jQueryUI widget (specifically the selectmenu at the moment) but still let jQueryUI handle the styling/theming.

Initializing jQueryUI widgets in template onRendered functions works just fine, as does destroying jQueryUI widgets, as necessary, in template onDestroyed functions. Calling `selectmenu('refresh')` on the option template's onRendered function does refresh the selectmenu when new options are available. However, I cannot find anywhere I can effectively call refresh when options are reactively removed such that the selectmenu is refreshed to the new, correct UI state -- not at the end of the event which changes the Meteor data context, not on the option template's onDestroyed function, and not a Tracker.autorun function tied to the appropriate data source.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>Proof of Concept</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myApp">
    {{> myForm}}
  </div>
</body>

<template name="myForm">
  <div>
    <div id="selectedEntries">
      <h3>Selected Entries</h3>
      <ul class="display-list">
        {{#each entry in selectedEntries}}
          {{> myForm_entry entry}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <form id="includeEntry">
      <select name="entryToInclude" id="entryToInclude">
        {{#each potentialEntry in availableEntries}}
          {{> myForm_option potentialEntry}}
        {{/each}}
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Include Entry">
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="myForm_entry">
  <li>
    <div class="button removeEntry" data-id="{{_id}}">X</div>
    <span>{{name}}</span>
  </li>
</template>

<template name="myForm_option">
  <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
Template.myForm.helpers({
  availableEntries: function () {
    return _.filter(Session.get('someEntries'), function(o) {
      return Session.get('selectedEntryIds').indexOf(o._id) == -1;
    });
  },
  selectedEntries: function () {
    return _.filter(Session.get('someEntries'), function(o) {
      return Session.get('selectedEntryIds').indexOf(o._id) != -1;
    });
  }
});

Template.myForm.events({
  'submit #includeEntry': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (_.isEmpty(Session.get('selectedEntryIds'))) {
      Session.set('selectedEntryIds', [$('#entryToInclude').val()]);
    } else {
      let selectedEntryIds = Session.get('selectedEntryIds');
      selectedEntryIds.push($('#entryToInclude').val());
      Session.set('selectedEntryIds', selectedEntryIds);
    }
    $('#entryToInclude').selectmenu('refresh')
  },
  'click .removeEntry': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let selectedEntryIds = Session.get('selectedEntryIds');
    selectedEntryIds = _.pull(selectedEntryIds, $(event.target).parent().attr('data-id'));
    Session.set('selectedEntryIds', selectedEntryIds);
  }
});

Template.myForm.onCreated(function () {
  let someEntries = [{
    _id:'1',
    name:'One'
  },{
    _id:'2',
    name:'Two'
  },{
    _id:'3',
    name:'Three'
  },{
    _id:'4',
    name:'Four'
  },{
    _id:'5',
    name:'Five'
  },{
    _id:'6',
    name:'Six'
  }];
  Session.set('someEntries', someEntries);
  Session.set('selectedEntryIds', []);
});

Template.myForm.onRendered(function () {
  $('#entryToInclude').selectmenu();
  $('input:submit').button();
});
Template.myForm_entry.onRendered(function () {
  $('.button').button();
});
Template.myForm_option.onRendered(function () {
  if ($('#entryToInclude').is(':ui-selectmenu')) {
    $('#entryToInclude').selectmenu('refresh');
  }
});

Template.myForm_option.onDestroyed(function () {
  $('#entryToInclude').selectmenu('refresh');
});

Tracker.autorun(function () {
  if (Session.get('selectedEntryIds')) {
    if ($('#entryToInclude').is(':ui-selectmenu')) {
      $('#entryToInclude').selectmenu('refresh');
    }
  }
});
```

The #entryToInclude selectmenu continues to include the entry that was just selected; selecting a second entry numbered as high or higher actually selects the subsequent entry (e.g. selecting 4 then 5 actually selects 4 and 6) except that selecting the last entry immediately after a successful selection does nothing but refresh the selectmenu.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a refresh to the entry template's onRendered function makes this work.

```
Template.myForm_entry.onRendered(function () {
  $('.button').button();
  if ($('#entryToInclude').is(':ui-selectmenu')) {
    $('#entryToInclude').selectmenu('refresh');
  }
});
```

But a better approach to the entire problem would be appreciated.